# Does colliderect work with classes, if so then how do I use it?

Tags: python, pygame

I am having an issue adding "colliderect" to my game. I have this class for setting values to the objects, and then one for drawing the items to the screen.

**Edited ** 
Throughout edits I have updated what my code is having issues with. I have yet to make any of the bel
ow solutions work with my class. All answers that have been given are very helpful, but I am still having the same issues. Collierect just doesn't want to work, when I use pygame.sprite.Sprite for collisions I get a sprite begs flashes when it contacts another sprite.rect, but the rect's movement doesn't reverse.

Help on either of these issues would be greatly appreciated, but until I get things solved I will leave the question open. 
**Error I was getting**

> if paddle1.Render().colliderect(ball):
>
> > AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'colliderect'

**Error I am getting now**

> if paddle1.Render().colliderect(ball):
>
> > AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'colliderect'

I don't know how to fix this issue.

**Here's my code for the ball**

```
                #Create a class named sprite to use for the paddles and the ball.
            class Object():
                def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
            # Set X value
                     self.x = x
            # Set Y value
                     self.y = y
            # Set Width of object
                     self.width = width
            # Set Height of object
                     self.height = height
            # Set the (default) color of the object
                     self.color = (255,255,255)        
            #attirbute for drawing the sprite(s) to the screen
                def Render(self):
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))
                    return self
             #Create the sprites       
            paddle1 = Object(50,175,25,150,color[0])
            paddle2 = Object(650,175,25,150,color[1])
            ball = Object(300,250,25,25, color[2])
```

**This is the code for colliderect**

```
            #Commands for ball collision
                if paddle1.Render().colliderect(ball):
                    if True:
                        pass #do something
                if paddle2.Render().colliderect(ball):
                    if True:
                        pass #do something
            # --- Drawing code should go here
```

Aside from the if statement, what am I missing for colliderect to work?

Comment: Python convention: Classes are prefixed with an upper case letter, but objects are lower case.  In short, `Paddle1`, `Paddle2`, and `Ball` should be `paddle1`, `paddle2`, and `ball`.  Since you go against the convention it gives the impression that `render()` is a static method.

Comment: btw, great job with http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve !  Refreshing!

Comment: Thank you! I had a couple of removed posts so I decided to read up on how to properly ask a question. 3rd times the charm!

Comment: I will go ahead and change that syntax for readability

Answer (score 0):

Your method `render()` that your wrote does not return any value (Ok, it returns `None`.)

Were you intending to return the rect at the end of that method?

```
def render(self):
     self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))
     return self.rect
```

Then you could chain your method calls like you want:

```
paddle2.render().colliderect(ball):
```

...although you probably need to calculate and set the ball's rect and pass it:

```
paddle2.render().colliderect(ball.rect):
```

I haven't used `pygame` so I'm helping a little blindly, but I think you have some confusion over classes.  Your sprite should be derived from `pygame.sprites.Sprite`.  Then you specialize your sprite to be the kind of sprite you want it to be, but pygame's sprite implements most of the underlying logic.

Here's an example sprite implementation: http://www.101computing.net/creating-sprites-using-pygame/

Comment: Sadly no, it is only registering 'Sprite' as a class name. If I change the name to something like Object or even just A, it still doesn't work

Comment: Wait ... You need to derive from pygame's Sprite.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought that link was to, that's why I said that Sprite was for my class, it doesn't work even if I change the class' name

Comment: Your class name isn't important.  What you derive your class from is.  `import pygame.sprite; class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite): [...]`

Comment: Sprite is just a name, I can change it to what ever. Sprite just made sense to me so I kept it, I should probably change the name to square or object to avoid confusion.

Comment: I appreciate the help with pygame.sprite but I actually was wondering if there was a way for colliderect to work wit the current class and drawing method that I have right now.

Comment: So you're intending to write your own Sprite from scratch?  You need a rect object as part of your implementation to work with colliderect.

Comment: I thought that the rect object for colliderect was made when I target paddle1.Render().colliderect(ball)
I was initially targeting just paddle1(ball). I thought that saying paddle1.render gives a rect object. 

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: I understand that I should be using sprites for this, but since it is a simple game of Pong, I thought that rectangles would do just fine, then I don't have to worry about images, blitting, or any of the other surface stuff that comes with pygame sprites.

Comment: I modified my answer.  I'm flying blind here -- I haven't used `pygame`.  I'm just reading the API definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might work. To use colliderect Pygame expects a `Rect(x,y,width,height)` or `Rect((x,y),(width,height))`.

So basically you want: `myrectangle1.colliderect(myrectangle2)`
Similarly to use collidepoint you need: `myrectangle1.collidepoint(mypoint1)`

```
            #Create a class named sprite to use for the paddles and the ball.
        class Object():
            def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        # Set X value
                 self.x = x
        # Set Y value
                 self.y = y
        # Set Width of object
                 self.width = width
        # Set Height of object
                 self.height = height
        # Create Rect of object=
                 self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        # Set the (default) color of the object
                 self.color = (255,255,255)        
        #attirbute for drawing the sprite(s) to the screen
            def Render(self):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color, self.rect)
                return self
         #Create the sprites       
        paddle1 = Object(50,175,25,150,color[0])
        paddle2 = Object(650,175,25,150,color[1])
        ball = Object(300,250,25,25, color[2])
```

alternatively if you don't want to have a self.rect attribute then you need:

```
            def Render(self):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,pygame.Rect(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height))
                return self
```

This Render method however will just draw your rectangle. 
If you want it to return the rectangle attribute of your object to test for collision then you need:

```
            def Render(self):
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color, self.rect) #draws the rect
                return self.rect #returns the rect
```

To check for collision you would need:

```
if paddle1.rect.colliderect(ball.rect): #this is why I think having a rect attribute is cleaner than calling pygame.Rect(x,y,w,h) all the time.
```

or:

```
if paddle1.pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height).colliderect(ball.pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)):
```

Comment: That makes total sense as to why it would work! I will go ahead and try that in a little bit today. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problems. Just one thing, if you just add the 'return self.rect' to your render you will be drawing your rectangle every time you check for a collision as well, since you are calling the .draw function in your Render. You might want to avoid that and do things separately. Use just the .rect attribute to check the collision and draw things at the end of the frame before refreshing the screen.

Comment: Yeah, I tried starting over last night and attempted working with pygame.sprite.Sprite, and I was having an issue with it drawing then updating themed drawing again. When working with sprites my movement wouldn't reverse on hit, the ball would just flash on the paddle and continue straight when I move it.

Comment: But now that doesn't even matter because I'm fairly confident that this will work for me :) thanks again Sorade

Comment: I tried adding both ways that you showed above, and both of them give me an error of Object has no attribute Rect (or rect). When i give object a value of self.rect= Rect(xywh), I get an error saying name Rect is not defined.

Comment: sorry you might need to use pygame.Rect(xywh) as the function call rather than Rect(xywh). also your class might need to by a child class of the Pygame Sprite class (but I don't think this is essential here). All the info you need is here: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html. I will edit my answer